# GTK based application outside desktop environment

Tags: c, linux, gtk, desktop

OK, I'm not having much success googling this so I hope this is not a question that's been beaten to death.

I want to program a media center / navigation system for a car. It will go onto a raspberry pi. I want to use clutter API to create the GUI which is GTK based. I want to embed NavIt into the program for the navigation part of things.

Basically I want to silent boot Linux and go straight into the program without starting a desktop environment at all.

Is this possible? Can I make a GTK based program that runs outside of a desktop environment?

Comment: Sure, GTK doesn't have any dependency on a desktop environment.

Comment: So I can just include GTK, initiate a full screen window object and I'm on my way to building my application?

Comment: @ReX357: Very much so. You'll probably have to setup the display server somehow, but the details depend on what graphics system you're going to use. But that can be done with a shell script, which at the end start your program. There's no requirement for a desktop environment running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone reading this and wondering the same, you can simply include GTK in your source and run:

```
startx ./myprogram
```

Starts the X11 server and then runs your program outside of the desktop environment. For the record, I have an install of archlinux with xfce4.

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand how the display is done on your navigation system. Is it a framebuffer, a Wayland, a stripped X11 server (with what window manager)?

[GTK3](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.11/) has several backends (provided by [GDK3](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/3.11/gdk3-General.html)), even including a [wayland](http://wayland.freedesktop.org/gtk.html) one.

Qt5 has also several backends.

Perhaps running a customized [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) server without a desktop but with a specialized [window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager) could be worthwhile (read about [EWMH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Window_Manager_Hints)). It certainly is possible on a Rasberry Pi (but I don't know the details).